# SkFlow - Implement Dropout or L2 Regularization with classifiers and regressors

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any simple way to implement regularization methods with the [SkFlow estimators](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/master/g3doc/api_docs/python/estimators.md)?

There is an [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/iris_custom_model.py) of implementing dropout in SkFlow, but it doesn't implement the estimators.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
regressor = skflow.TensorFlowDNNRegressor(
    hidden_units=[
      20,
      30,
      30,
      30,
      20
    ],
    steps=steps,
    learning_rate=0.3,
    batch_size=32)

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

If there isn't any simple way to implement regularization with these SkFlow estimators yet, then I would appreciate if someone could show, explain, or point me to something that would give me basically the same effect as the TensorFlowDNNRegressor but I could add regularization to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses the new `tf.contrib.learn` api, which allows both dropout and an optimizer.

```
val_monitor = learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
  X_validate,
  y_validate,
  every_n_steps=100,
  early_stopping_metric="loss",
  early_stopping_metric_minimize=True,
  early_stopping_rounds=1000)

feature_columns = [contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=2)]

regressor = learn.DNNRegressor(
  feature_columns=feature_columns,
  hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256],
  model_dir="tmp/network_model",
  config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=10),
  optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
    learning_rate=0.1,
    #l2_regularization_strength=0.0001
  ),
  dropout=0.1)

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, steps=500000, batch_size=32, monitors=[val_monitor])
```

I'm still not sure how how to get this to work with a [decaying learning rate](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#decaying-the-learning-rate).

More information about [validation monitoring](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/monitors/index.html) and the [api](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#DNNRegressor).